# multiplicación de cantidades

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy tratando de multiplicar cantidades en este caso importe es el precio que se multiplica si tiene cambios pero cantidad no se multiplica quiza sea problema de mi logica quisiera que me ayuden por favor.
Nbatida es el numero que multiplica a cantidad y a importe.

el importe es igual ala cantidad por el precio.
la cantidad es igual Nbatida(el que multiplica) por la cantidad.

con cantidad tengo el problema que no hace el cambio de los valores que mando a guardar pero si reconoce el cambio internamente ya que el importe si lleva los valores correctos.

```
function setNbatida(event, obj, idx){
    event.preventDefault();
    detalles[idx].Nbatida = parseInt(obj.value);
    recalcular(idx);
}  
function recalcular(idx){
    console.log(detalles[idx].Nbatida);
    console.log((detalles[idx].Nbatida * detalles[idx].cantidad * detalles[idx].precio));
    console.log((detalles[idx].Nbatida * detalles[idx].cantidad));
    let cantidad = detalles[idx].cantidad * detalles[idx].Nbatida;
    let importe = cantidad * detalles[idx].precio;
    let cantidadReal  = cantidad;

    $('#importe'+idx).html(detalles[idx].moneda + ' ' + importe);
    $('#cantidad'+idx).html(cantidad);

    detalles[idx].importe = importe;

    detalles[idx].cantidadReal = cantidad;

    calcularTotales();
}

function calcularTotales(){  
    let subtotal = 0;
    let total = 0;
    let subtotalFinal = 0;
    let totalFinal = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<detalles.length; i++){
        if(detalles[i].estado == 1){

            subtotal += detalles[i].importe;
        }
    }
    $('#subtotal').html(detalles[i].moneda + ' ' + subtotal);
    $('#subtotal_Batida').html(detalles[i].moneda + ' ' + subtotal);
    totalFinal = Math.round(subtotal);
    $('#total').html(detalles[i].moneda + ' ' + totalFinal);
    $('#total_Batida').html(detalles[i].moneda + ' ' + totalFinal);
}
```

estos datos están multiplicados por 20 el dato de subtotal tiene el resultado bien pero en el caso de la cantidad no ha cambiado el dato aun que si ha tomado ese valor para poder multiplicar subtotal

[image: imagen]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema y dónde es el problema?

Comment: en la parte de recalcular, cantidad no refleja el cambio que se hace por medio de Nbatida que es la variable que multiplica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debe parsear directamente cuando extraiga el objeto:

```
let cantidad = parseInt(detalles[idx].cantidad) * parseInt(detalles[idx].Nbatida);
```

Comment: ok amigos gracias por su ayuda